# Multicolumn menu DNN7 with Bootstrap

Tags: menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, dotnetnuke, multiple-columns

I'm trying to achieve this on DNN7 with bootstrap. I have already bootstrap working great on my DNN 7.4 version, but I would like to perform a multicolumn menu working on DNN.

Comment: Please take the time to read the help->tour, in particular the part about no chit-chat.

Comment: Dear Anthon, I'm not trying to chit-chat. I'm trying to get help on this matter. The question may be too generic, but it is clear. I didn't find any solution online about implementing a multicolumn menu with bootstrap3 and DotNetNuke v.7.

Comment: I was referring to the stuff that I already removed  ("Thanks .." and "Greetings"), so other people don't have to read through that, question irrelevant, material. Your post showed up in the Help & Improvement queue (for me to improve) after three people independently indicated in Triage that it needed improvement. I was not talking about the rest of your post.